# I'm trying to set up python in notepad++ and it can't understand my filepath that has a space in it

Tags: python, configuration, notepad++, filepath

I'm using this tutorial: https://silentcrash.com/2016/12/run-python-script-notepad/

The example for Python 3 includes the folder "Program Files (x86)", which I assume is not necessary, but I would still like to know how to fix this problem if it comes up in the future and I don't have another way of doing it.

So what happens is that the program assumes the space is the end of the command and it move on to the argument as seen here:

[The Program to Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOmxq.jpg)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPx2g.jpg)

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
An attempt was made to execute the below command.
------------------------------------------------
Command: C:\Program
Arguments: Files\Python37\Lib\idlelib.py "new 2"
Error Code: 2
```

Is there any way to write the file path such that it won't be split up like this?

Comment: You need to find the actual path for python. In Windows it's usually in `C:\python37\` not in Program Files. Also, please give VSCode and/or SublimeText a try. They are so much better than Notepad++.

Comment: Also, the actual error you get is because there's a space in `C:\Program Files` and the runner thinks the program is `C:\Program` and the rest are the arguments. Try putting the whole python.exe path between quotes.

Comment: I understand that it is due to the fact that there is a space. I mentioned that in the question. I cannot seem to find the "C:\Python37" folder. When I installed Python, I chose the option to put it in Program Files. I can see the Python37 folder in Program Files.  Also, I do have VSCode installed, but I at least want to be able to do this one thing. I get that some programs just have advantages over others, but I want to at least run a program before I move onto another editor.

Comment: If you have it in `C:\Program Files`, try putting it between quotes: `"C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\idlelib\idle.py" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`. I'm not entirely sure but I remember somewhere in the documentation mentioning not putting it in Program Files precisely because of problems with the space. If all fails, try uninstalling it and reinstalling on `C:\python37`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround your arguments with quotes when they contain spaces. In your example, you would use the following command in the Run... dialog:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\idlelib.py" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

I found a helpful hint on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/1284388/2004) that will stop the console window from closing when your script finishes. However, note that it now needs an extra set of quotes.

```
cmd /k ""C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\idlelib.py" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)""
```